# JFR ExecutionSample event with TraceID

Tags: transactions, httprequest, opentracing, jfr

I want to be able to relate JFR ExecutionSample events to trace ID/transaction ID/HTTP request etc. Any way to be able to trace the REST call thru several microservices. All this **WITHOUT** changing the application code.

Any help will be appreciated.